# Expresso Store - Go straight to checkout when adding item to cart

Tags: expresso-store

Is it possible to go straight to the checkout page when the user adds an item to the cart?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would achieve that using the [return="" parameter on the product tag](https://exp-resso.com/docs/store/product_tag.html#return).

```
{exp:store:product return="checkout"}
    <!-- add to cart form -->
{/exp:store:product}
```

See also the example templates which are installed with Store (in your `store_example` template group, or in the `third_party/store/templates` directory).

Comment: Many thanks once again Adrian, I have been using the sample templates as a guide but had missed the return parameter.